# Redux Local Storage Workflow

Tags: react-redux, local-storage

I am using `Redux` and would like to store some state on `local storage`.

I only like to store the token which I receive from the server. There are other things in the store that I don't like to store.

The workflow that I found on google is to grab from `local storage` in `initial store map`.

Then he uses `store.subscribe` to update the local storage on regular interval.

That is valid if we are storing the entire store. But for my case, the token is only updated when user logs out or a new user logs in.

I think `store.subscribe` is an overkill.

I also read that updating `local storage` in `reducers` is not the `redux` way.

Currently, I am updating `local storage` in `action` before `reducer` is updated.

Is it the correct flow or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you found was likely about serializing the entire state tree into localstorage with every state change, allowing users to close the tab without worrying about constantly saving since it will always be up to date in LocalStorage.

However, it's clear that this isn't what you are looking for, as you are looking to cache specific priority data in LocalStorage, not the entire state tree.

You are also correct about updating LocalStorage as part of a reducer being an anti-pattern, as all side-effects are supposed to be localized to action creators.

Thus you should be reading from and writing to LocalStorage in your action creators.

For instance, your action creator for retrieving a token could look something like:

```
const TOKEN_STORAGE_KEY = 'TOKEN';    

export function fetchToken() {
    // Assuming you are using redux-thunk for async actions
    return dispatch => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_STORAGE_KEY);

        if (token && isValidToken(token)) {
            return dispatch(tokenRetrieved(token));
        }

        return doSignIn().then(token => {
            localStorage.setItem(TOKEN_STORAGE_KEY, token);        
            dispatch(tokenRetrieved(token));
        }
    }
}

export function tokenRetrieved(token) {
    return {
        type: 'token.retrieved',
        payload: token
    };
}
```

And then somewhere early on in your application boot, such as in one of your root component's `componentWillMount` lifecycle methods, you dispatch the `fetchToken` action.

`fetchToken` takes care of both checking LocalStorage for a cached token as well as storing a new token there when one is retrieved.